# What is PHP as "Personal Home Page" and "PHP Hypertext Preprocessor"?

Tags: php

What is PHP as "Personal Home Page" and "PHP Hypertext Preprocessor"?

Comment: sometimes i think there's only stackoverflow on the internet... what happened to google and wikipedia where it only takes 5 seconds to find an answer to such a simple question...

Comment: You can read more about PHP here: http://thecodetutorial.com/what-is-php-your-first-program/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It ***is***:

**PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor**

Previously it ***was***:

**Personal Home Page**

**See:**

**[The History of PHP](http://www.nusphere.com/php/php_history.htm)**

> PHP was written in the C programming
>   language by Rasmus Lerdorf in 1994 for
>   use in monitoring his online resume
>   and related personal information. For
>   this reason, PHP originally stood for
>   "**Personal Home Page**". Lerdorf combined
>   PHP with his own Form Interpreter,
>   releasing the combination publicly as
>   **PHP/FI** (generally referred to as PHP
>   2.0) on June 8, 1995. Two programmers, Zeev Suraski and Andi Gutmans, rebuilt
>   PHP's core, releasing the updated
>   result as PHP/FI 2 in 1997. The
>   acronym was formally changed to **PHP:
>   HyperText Preprocessor**, at this time.
>   (This is an example of a recursive
>   acronym: where the acronym itself is
>   in its own definition.)

Comment: LOL Rasmus Lerdorf wrote an entire language just to monitor his "online resume and related personal information".. what a guy.

Answer (score 5):

php is called hypertext preprocessor as its libraries are already compiled.when any person request for any php page in the address bar of the browser that request is first sent to the server then server interpret php files and return back response in form of Html.

Answer (score 3):

"Personal Home Page Tools" was the **original** name of [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), now it is a recursive acronym "PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor". "PHP/FI" was also another name for PHP.