# Is PHP really a "Hypertext Preprocessor" as the name suggests?

Tags: php, programming-languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is PHP as “Personal Home Page” and “PHP Hypertext Preprocessor”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043179/what-is-php-as-personal-home-page-and-php-hypertext-preprocessor)

I get that the name PHP is a recursive acronym. Fine

I'm not sure why PHP has the Preprocessor and Hypertext parts in its name.

A preprocessor is a program that processes input data and its output is the input of another program.

PHP seems just like an interpreter to me. What exact thing makes it a preprocessor?

Is it called a preprocessor because it's output is usually sent to a web server to deliver over the web? So is it the preprocessor to the web server? Is that where it gets its Preprocessor name?

Does it get the Hypertext part of its name because PHP is embedded in HTML?

Did I just work out why PHP is called PHP Hypertext Preprocessor or is there more to it or am I wrong and it is something else?

I've just never read anywhere what makes PHP a preprocessor and why it has Hypertext and Preprocessor in its name. I would really like to nail this.

I know that PHP was originally called Personal Home Page. That's easy to understand. Please make it easy to understand PHP Hypertext Preprocessor too.

The hardest thing in the whole programming language of PHP is its name.

Comment: Just like the name says: it preprocesses Hypertext.

Comment: yes that is pretty much the deal. PHP "pre-processes" html (client-side) code and then sends the page to the browser. The browser then takes what is sent and renders it.

Comment: It isn't duplicate... I can't vote for reopen.

Comment: Actually PHP doesn't do anything with the hypertext part of any document. Yes, it can parse hypertext, but is parse==pre-process true?

Comment: @Vili the name is pretty much an indicator for nothing nowadays given that PHP has grown a lot from it's infant days. It's a teenager now and a general purpose language. There is no value in discussing the name.

Comment: This isn't a fracking duplicate!  @mudge: to answer your question, originally all PHP did was load a bunch of intermixed HTML and output "dynamic" HTML.  Now, the name is ludicrous as PHP outputs virtually anything from Excel and Word docs, to PDFs, console, first-class GUIs as well as web pages.

Comment: I didnt CV as duplicate btw. I closed as *too localized*.

Comment: My question is definitely not an exact duplicate. I'm not asking what, I'm asking why, and I'm asking for an explanation of why. Please vote to reopen.

Comment: Mudge, for you, PHP means **Please Halt Profanity**.

Comment: @mudge Dont bother about what the name stood for or is now. Whatever definition you can come up for a *Hypertext preprocessor* is nothing that would fit PHP's feature richness nowadays. PHP is a general purpose scripting language.

Comment: @Gordon Yes, I know that and that is not the point.  The point is that I want to understand the name or why it was originally called PHP Hypertext Preprocessor. If this reason is a history lessen then I want the history lessen. I will bother what the name stood for because that's my question and that's what I want to understand.

Comment: @webbiedave lol No kidding :)

Comment: @mudge: http://php.net/manual/en/history.php.php

Comment: @mudge: I would write Rasmus Lerdorf, Andi Gutmans or Zeev Suraski yourself and ask them (they have websites and, with a little creativity, you'll be able to find their emails). They may very well be the only ones who know the answer!